# retry mechanism for transactions in web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, ethereumj, java

In my Java-web-application I have (with one click) to send about 120 transactions after each other from the same address to the same smartcontract.

My question: is there any java libraries or implemented "retry mechanism" for handling very long pending transactions, or a way to save transactions in a persistent Queue (cause i can't just save them in memory) before sending them to the Blockchain.

Comment: Could you please clarify if with "Java-web-application" you mean "Javascript in the web page (client side)", or "Java code on the server", or even web3j.io android app?

Comment: hallo Mr. @MarcoOttolini , java code on the server side(backend).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to broadcast 120 transactions, but the transaction no 50 gets stuck because it has a low gas price.

You can reconstruct the tx number 50, set a higher gas price and broadcast the new tx.

As long as **the sending address** and **the nonce for tx no 50** are the same, everything else can be different: the amount sent, the type of transaction, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm looking exactly for a library or some implemented and already tested methods which manage this problem in the background

Comment: You mentioned `web3j`. That is a rock solid library for dealing with ethereum transactions. Rather than trying to figure out if there's any tool to match your current app flow and config to do this, I think it would be much easier (or actually doable) for you to build such a mini class yourself.

Comment: right writing it is not the problem, but testing it was really painfull.